# My VBA Excel 2013 Code isn't compiling

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

When I run this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim range1 As Integer
Dim range2 As Integer
range1 = 53
range2 = 102

For i = range1 To range2
    For j = (range1 - 50) To (range2 - 50)

        If Cells(2, i) = Cells(2, j) Then
            If Cells(7, i) > Cells(7, j) Then
            Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'Went up; Green
            ElseIf Cells(7, i) = Cells(7, j) Then
            Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'No change; Grey
            Else
            Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'Went down; Red
        End If

    Next j
    If Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 Then 'Hasn't Changed; No Fill
    Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'New Song; Blue
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

An error appears saying:
Compile error: Next without For
However there definitely is a For for each Next.
So where did I go wrong?
Note: The '37's are just filler numbers, I know it appears as light blue.

Comment: You are missing an `End If` somewhere within your `For j` loop (possibly just before the one `End If` that is there?), so it is thinking that it is finding a `Next` while still within an `If` and there is no `For` within the `If`.  Learn to indent your code within your `If` statements and those sort of issues become very noticeable.

Comment: @YowE3K You're right, but when I load the spreadsheet nothing happens, if you could tell the cell colors of Cells B53:B102 were supposed to change depending on the values of G53:G102 compared to G3:G52. But nothing happened, do you know what went wrong in that regard?

Comment: You mention `B53:B102` but your code is processing `BA2:CX2`.  Parameters to `Cells` are `row, column` but I think you are using `column, row`.  (So change `Cells(2, i)` to `Cells(i, 2)`, or `Cells(i, "B")`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indenting your code in a consistent manner gives the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim range1 As Integer
    Dim range2 As Integer
    range1 = 53
    range2 = 102

    For i = range1 To range2
        For j = (range1 - 50) To (range2 - 50)

            If Cells(2, i) = Cells(2, j) Then
                If Cells(7, i) > Cells(7, j) Then
                    Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'Went up; Green
                ElseIf Cells(7, i) = Cells(7, j) Then
                    Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'No change; Grey
                Else
                    Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'Went down; Red
                End If

                Next j ' <--- This Next has no For associated with it

                If Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 Then 'Hasn't Changed; No Fill
                    Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'New Song; Blue
                End If
            Next i
        End Sub
```

You can very quickly tell by the indentation levels that the `Next j` has no `For` statement associated with it within the current `If` block.  This is why you get your error.

I suspect that you intended to have an `End If` just before that `Next j` and therefore your code would look like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim range1 As Integer
    Dim range2 As Integer
    range1 = 53
    range2 = 102

    For i = range1 To range2
        For j = (range1 - 50) To (range2 - 50)

            If Cells(2, i) = Cells(2, j) Then
                If Cells(7, i) > Cells(7, j) Then
                    Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'Went up; Green
                ElseIf Cells(7, i) = Cells(7, j) Then
                    Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'No change; Grey
                Else
                    Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'Went down; Red
                End If
            End If    

        Next j

        If Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 Then 'Hasn't Changed; No Fill
            Cells(2, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'New Song; Blue
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```